# How can I relocate main() to 0x00000000?

Tags: gcc, assembly, ld, avr

Here's the nm dump of my program.

```
00000000 T __ctors_end
00000000 T __ctors_start
00000000 T __dtors_end
00000000 T __dtors_start
00000000 a __tmp_reg__
00000000 T __trampolines_end
00000000 T __trampolines_start
00000000 T setup
00000001 a __zero_reg__
0000003d a __SP_L__
0000003e a __SP_H__
0000003f a __SREG__
00000072 T __vector_15
00000086 T main
000000a8 A __data_load_end
000000a8 A __data_load_start
000000a8 T _etext
00800100 D _edata
00800100 T _end
00810000 T __eeprom_end
```

The architecture is AVR, and I need to get main() back up to 0x00000000 in order for the chip that I'm running this code on to execute properly. It should be as simple as a linker script, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you sure you want `main` at `0x00000000`? The AVR documentation I've seen says that the first code run would be a bootloader located from `256B` through `4KB`, which would then jump to the main program.

Comment: Well, `0x00000000` is the address I need `main()` at in the binary file because I am flashing the binary to start at `256B` in order to save programming time. But, thank you for the observation.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. Normally, the file format for writing flash (such as, for example Intel Hex or S Record) takes target address into account and it shouldn't matter what address it is in the file. Sounds like you're creating a binary image file directly. If your current file has main starting at address 256 in that file, what is in the first 256 bytes? And how much programming time does it take to program 256 bytes on your system? That should be pretty fast.

Comment: By binary I mean the actual byte code generated by the compiler, and it is in the format of Intel Hex. Sorry for not clarifying that. `main()` isn't starting at `256B` in my hex file because I start programming the first address of the file at `256B` on the chip itself. Hence, why I am in need of having `main()` start at the first address of the file. In regards to time, it's not that big of an issue, but it's just more convenient for me to program it the way I am instead of appending `256 bytes` of `0's` at the beginning of the file each time I compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where `main()` is in memory. Simply put a `jump` instruction to its address at the reset vector, or `0x0000` in application memory.

Answer (score 0):

I used to program for AVR and as I know the only way to change `main()` entry is fuse bits. But you just can to put in the back of FLASH for bootloader. Depending on chip main starts in different places, I'm not sure but on AVR it should be something like `0x20` to `0x100`.

It is because at the beginning there is RESET vector, registers and interrupt vectors. 
This structure helps very much, once I had a project on which I wasn't able to use watchdog so the only way to trigger reset was overflow.

Also, I've read your comment. You don't need to put 256 bytes of `0x00` that place is for some registers (AVR registers are divided in to places one is SRAM, other FLASH) and interrupt vectors, so if you use lets say timer or UART and your code start at `0x00` so initialization of these would destroy your code.

It is designed to work, I think redesigning would spoil that. But if you really want this, you can try to add `-Ttext=0x0000` this flag. **This may compile it as you want but I do not recomend doing that.**

Comment: `-Ttext=0x0000` didn't work because `main()` isn't at the beginning of the text section, `setup()` is which is why it is found above `main()` in the numerical dump from `nm`. But, okay. I'm interested in taking advantage of the `AVR` architecture to its fullest, so tell me how you think that I can utilize the first `256B` of flash memory to jump to `main()` at whatever address that it may be at.

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan First I want to ask what chip do you have and what compiler are you using.

Comment: I actually ended up solving my problem by putting a `jump` instruction to `main()` at 0x000 after disabling the fuse that was pointed to address of the bootloader for booting. Thank you for your help though!